# Placing an image below a table which relate to each other on the same page

Tags: tables, graphics, positioning

I have a table made up of the following LaTeX:

```
\begin{table} [htbp]
\centering
\begin{tabular} {lrrr}
    \toprule
    \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{Category}} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{Type}} \\
    \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{Automatic}} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{Semi-automatic}} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{Manual}} \\
    \midrule
    Category 1                              &   0 &   1 &   1 \\
    Category 2                              &  20 &  28 &  12 \\        
    ...
    \midrule
    Total                                   & 121 & 170 &  59 \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption{Text of caption...}.
\label{tab:myTable}
\end{table}
```

Which works perfectly well. But I would like to place a related chart beneath this table. The chart is written in Excel and saved as a .png graphic file.

Is there a way I can 'link' the table and graphic file so that they are always together and remain on the same page, a float or other LaTeX form?

I am looking for something like this for the page layout:

[image]

Comment: if both will fit on the same page, and the "graphic" is really a table in disguise, you could just put them both into the same float -- unless you insist on listing one in the "list of tables" and the other in the "list of figures".  (and even then, there is probably a workaround.)

Comment: An interesting idea. However, the graphics tend to be bar and column charts, word clouds and tree-maps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing illegal or improper about including a graphic (with an `\includegraphics` directive, say) in a `table` environment. To generate a caption of the form "Figure : ...", be sure to load the `caption` package and use a `\captionof{figure}{...}` instruction

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption} % for "\captionof" macro
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} % omit 'demo' option in real document
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[p]
\centering
\begin{tabular} {lrrr}
    \toprule
    \textbf{Category} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{Type}} \\
     & \textbf{Automatic} & \textbf{Semi-automatic} & \textbf{Manual} \\
    \midrule
    Category 1   &   0 &   1 &   1 \\
    Category 2   &  20 &  28 &  12 \\        
    \dots \\
    \midrule
    Total        & 121 & 170 &  59 \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption{Text of table caption \dots}
\label{tab:myTable}

\vspace*{2cm}  % set amount of vertical offset
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth,
                 height=1\textwidth]{test}
\captionof{figure}{Text of figure caption \dots} 
\label{fig:myFigure}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The only issue I have with this is that if I put a label on the graphic such as `\label{fig:This figure}`, LaTeX will treat the graphic as a table. Can this be changes so that LaTeX treats the graphic as a figure?

Comment: @MrMorgan -  Should the figure-related caption be numbered, e.g., as "Figure 1"?

Comment: Yes. Both table and figure are linked in that they show the same data, but they should have distinct table and figure numbering.

Comment: @MrMorgan - That'll be an easy fix. Give me a couple of minutes to update the code.